# sort data in Ascending order POSTGRES SQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

I have data in the format (Before sorting)

```
"8 - 15days"    "0"
"0 - 24hrs" "0"
"above 30days"  "0"
"2 - 7days" "0"
"16 - 30days"   "0"
```

I need to sort the data in order like this(After sorting)

```
"0 - 24hrs" "0"
"2 - 7days" "0"
"8 - 15days"    "0"
"16 - 30days"   "0"
"above 30days"  "0"
```

Can anyone help me to sort the data.
I tried order by but it is not sorting the data in the way I need.

Comment: Please add your schema?

Answer (score 1):

If the column with the text in it is called `x`, you could use

```
ORDER BY x !~ '^[[:digit:]]',
         regexp_replace(x, '^([[:digit:]]*).*$', '0\1')::integer
```